# Input image from gdrive into my email template using apps script and html

Tags: html, google-apps-script

i use this code in html to input image in email when run thru apps script

but then, the code seems like cannot read the image even though i have changed the image access to general with link.

this is the code

```
<img src="{{https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ewi5KgPDOMYTy9ebFBate6rfw0IsoFIN/view?usp=drive_link}}"/>
```

I need to include that particular image in my email template.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code worked for me to embed images in emails sent via apps script.

```
  // Fetch image from drive as blob
  var myimage = DriveApp.getFolderById('drive_folder_id').getFilesByName(`file_name.png`).next().getBlob()

  var adminEmail = "abc@test123.com"

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "user@test123.com",
    subject: "Email title",
    htmlBody: '<html><body><div>Some text<br /><br /><table width="100%"><tr><td align="center"><img src="cid:pngimage" style="width:256px" align="middle"></td></tr></table><br/><br/>Regards,<br />Sender</span></div></body></html>',
    inlineImages:
      {
        pngimage: myimage
      }
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).